# image rotate 360 degree on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

Need your help developers, 
I am using images as a menu. I just want when i click on image it rotate 360 degree and then another page is open. 
i try this.

```
<style>
    .image {
        overflow: hidden;
        transition-duration: 0.8s;
        transition-property: transform;
    }
    .image:active {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
</style>
```

html:

```
<img class="image" src="img path">
```

in this code image rotation is depend on click time and i want user just click once image rotate 360 degree and the link page display.
but this is not i want. 
I am using jqueryMobile and phonegap

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the link url in the image as a data attribute:

```
<img id="theimage" data-linkurl="#page2"src="http://makeameme.org/media/templates/120/grumpy_cat.jpg" alt=""  />
```

Then when you handle the click event,

You add the animation class.

You add an animationEnd handler that fires when the animation is complete. Use one() instead of on() as you only want this handler to fire once.

In the animationEnd handler you remove the animation class (so you can add it again next time), get the url from the data-attribute, and then navigate to the page.

```
$("#theimage").on("click", function(){       
    $(this).addClass("imageRot").one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend', function () {
        $(this).removeClass("imageRot"); //remove anim class
        var url = $(this).data('linkurl'); //get url from data-attribute
        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", url); //navigate to page      
    });
});
```

For the animation class I have used @cracker's spin animation (thanks cracker!):

```
.imageRot {
   -webkit-animation:spin 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation:spin 2s ease-in-out;
    animation:spin 2s ease-in-out;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin { 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } 
}
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gx8bj7bo/4/)**

Comment: @Rohit, you are welcome. If this works for you, please consider accepting the answer so users who search for this later will know the question had a solution.

Comment: one more question i have folder it contain html files.I have to link that file using main.html. How can i do it using data-linkurl
i try this :
 data-linkurl="#www/file.html but it fail to load
any suggestion.

Comment: @Rohit, if it is an external page, you don't need the # character, just the relative address e.g. 'filename.html' or if it is in a subfolder 'foldername/filename.html'

Comment: it gives me Error Loading Page

Comment: @Rohit, what text are you putting between the quotes in data-linkurl=''? Where is the HTML file located? Same folder as current page?

Comment: data-linkurl="www/file.html"
but main.html is out of this folder.

Comment: @Rohit, is www the name of a folder right below where main.html is, and file.html is in that www folder?

Comment: yes www is folder name
file.html is located in this folder but main.html is out of www folder.

Comment: @Rohit, to be clear: www is a direct child folder of the one where main.html resides?

Comment: i have project folder, inside a project folder there is another folder called as a www and inside this www the html files are saved.
but my main.html file is outside of www folder. So i have to link a file which save in www folder through main.html
project structure
    <project folder>
    www
    -res
    --icons
    --screens
    -file.html
    - other html
    main.html

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
<style>
  .image {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.8s;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
  }

  .image:active {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
</style>
```

1. You didn't include a webkit option (`-webkit-*`) in `transition`.
2. You didn't include a non-webkit option in `transform`.

because of that, no matter what browser you were using, something were missing (`transform` or `transition`), and therefore the code didn't work on any browser.

**edit**: I noticed it wasn't what you were asking for. I don't believe that it can be done with CSS only. If you want, you can do it with jQuery:

```
<script>
  $(".image").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("clicked").delay(800).removeClass("clicked");
  });
</script>

<style>
  .image {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.8s;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
  }

  .image.clicked {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but 1st solution is the same which i mention in my question.Effect is same.

Comment: @Rohit because Omar, that terrorist (Sorry, I'm Israeli that lives under fire scinse I was 8 so I can't be nice to him), changed the code (You can see it in the edit log). I fixed it again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to try using

```
.image {
   -webkit-animation:spin 4s ease-in-out; // No more infinite
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear;
    animation:spin 4s linear;
}


@-moz-keyframes spin {
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin { 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
```

OR

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {  
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.rotate {
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4.5s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

### [DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/Ugc5g/2691/)

### [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/FmLbd/11/)

Comment: Demo 1 is good but i want after click on image, image should rotate and then next page is open.

Comment: is hover effect is working in mobile phones.because at the end its a mobile app. So i need solution according this.
Thank you.

Comment: @Rohit, why don't you try once and let me know is working or not!!

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<img src = "some_image.png" alt = "test" class = "rotative" />
```

CSS

```
.canRotate
{
    -webkit-animation: FullRotation 3s ease-out;
    -o-animation: FullRotation 3s ease-out;
    -ms-animation: FullRotation 3s ease-out;
    -moz-animation: FullRotation 3s ease-out;
    animation: FullRotation 3s ease-out;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes FullRotation
{
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes FullRotation
{
    from { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes FullRotation
{
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes FullRotation
{
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes FullRotation
{
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

JavaScript

```
function RotateOnClickAndOpenPage(classname, url)
{
    var elts = document.getElementsByClassName(classname);

    for(var i = 0; i < elts.length; ++i)
    {
        elts[i].onclick = function(){
            this.style.className = "canRotate";
            var that = this;
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.open(url);
                that.style.className = "cannotRotate";
            }, 3000);
        };
    }
}

// Exemple
RotateOnClickAndOpenPage("rotative", "http://www.google.fr");
```

Comment: thanks you imagine breaker
ezanker solutions work perfect for me.